# Curve object is not callable error vPython

Tags: python

I'm new to vPython and Python in general and got this error when I was trying to create a catenoid. I was able to call a curve object earlier in the code that works fine but when I tried to do it a second time using the exact same syntax I get the aforementioned error. I imagine it is a fairly simple error but Id really appreciate if someone could help me out. The error occurs on line 11.

```
from visual import *
import math
curve=curve(color=color.green)
thStep=math.pi/1000
c=10 
theta=0
z=4 
a=.5
t=-z 
tStep=0.1
cur=curve(color=color.blue)
while theta<=(2*math.pi):
 x=c*(math.cosh(z/c))*math.cos(theta)
 y=c*(math.cosh(z/c))*math.sin(theta)
 curve.append(pos=(x,y,z))
 while t<=z:
    cur.append(pos=(t,a*math.cosh(t/a),0))
    t +=tStep
theta += thStep
```

Comment: You are overriding the `curve` method with a variable with the same name. Use another name for that variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with this line:

```
curve=curve(color=color.green)
```

You are assigning `curve` to something else and thus, it no longer points to the function. When you use `curve` again, you are referencing the value you assigned to it, which is not a function and so, not callable.

To help fix this issue, you should use a separate name for the variable.

Comment: Ok. So my error was making a curve object called curve.